# hierarchal permission on same model

Tags: python, django, permissions

Sorry, I couldn't find a suitable title, please edit the title if you understood the problem.

I want to achieve 4 level hierarchy (django Group): Country-Manager,State-Manager, City-Manager and Field-staff.

One user can belong to only one group at a time and any user can add a lead.

I have a model named Lead and I want to realize the following hierarchy:

"`User of higher level (say State-Manager) can view leads added by him and and all entries added by users of lower level (say City-Manager and Field Staff) but can not view entries added by other users of same level or higher lever (say Country-Manager)"`

To keep track who has added the entry, I am saving user and Group object as foreign key in the Lead model.

Please suggest any strategy or  code snippet.

--

p.s: I am on Django 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with help of mixins. ( http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/05/17/exploring-mixins-django-model-inheritance/ )

for I create a Hierarchy class:

```
class Hierarchy(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

    def get_children(self):
        return self._default_manager.filter(parent=self)

    def get_descendants(self):
        descs = set(self.get_children())
        for node in list(descs):
            descs.update(node.get_descendants())
        return descs

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and inherited it in class named GroupHirerarchy:

```
class GroupHierarchy(Hierarchy):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.group.name
```

Now I can get children of a group using
group_object.get_children()
and all descendants by :
group_object.get_descendants()

Now using this I achieve  get hierarchical permission on model:

```
glist = []
groups = request.user.groups.all() 
for group in groups:
        try:
            group_hierarchy = GroupHierarchy.objects.get(group = group)
            group_descendants = group_hierarchy.get_descendants()
            for group_descendant in group_descendants:
                glist.append(Group.objects.get(name=group_descendant.group))
        except:
            pass
    obj =  Model.objects.filter(user_group__in = glist)
```